# Show the sum for multiple items

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I've a data dictionary, I want to pickup some items for exemple at the 2nd range, from different lists as value of dictionary every key start with 111####, I created this method but how, I can get the sum off all items and insert it at QTableWidget cell?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QTableWidget, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QTableWidgetItem)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor 
from PyQt5 import QtCore

data = {'1111':['Title 1','12521','94565','','','','684651','','','44651','','',''], '1112':['Title 2','65115','','466149','46645','555641','','','','412045','98416','',''], '1113':['Title 3','243968','','','466149','46645','555641','98656','','','412045','98416','','']} 

class Table(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.setupUi()

def setuptUI(self):
  self.setWindowTitle("QTableWidgetItem")
                self.resize(1200, 800)
                conLayout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.tableWidget =QTableWidget(self)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(55)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(14)
    conLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

def setdata(self, k, v, n, m):
    i= 1
    l = str(k*10)
    while I < 4
            item = self.data.get(str(int(l)+i))[v]
            print(item)
            i= i+1
            if v== " ":
                  break
            #sum_instruction
    newItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
    newItem.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0)))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(m, n, newItem)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    windows = Table(data)
    windows.setdata(k="113", v=5, n=25, m=4
    windows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QTableWidget, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QTableWidgetItem)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor 
from PyQt5 import QtCore

#                                                             vvvvvv
data = {'1111':['Title 1','12521', '94565','',      '',      '777777','684651','','','44651','','',''], 
        '1112':['Title 2','65115', '',     '466149','46645', '555641','','','','412045','98416','',''], 
        '1113':['Title 3','243968','',     '',      '466149','46645', '555641','98656','','','412045','98416','','']} 
#                                                             ^^^^^^

class Table(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):  
        conLayout        = QHBoxLayout(self)     # self
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(55)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(14)
        conLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

    def setdata(self, k, v, n, m):
        print(k, v, n, m)
        i = 1
#        l = str(k*10)
        l = str(int(k)*10)
        s = 0

        while i < 4:
            item = self.data.get(str(int(l)+i))[v]
            print(item)
            i = i+1
#            if v == " ":
#                break
            #sum_instruction
            s = s + (int(item) if item else 0)

            newItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
            newItem.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0)))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(m, n, newItem)
            n += 1                                            # +++

        newItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(s))
        newItem.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.blue)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(m, n, newItem)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    windows = Table(data)

#    windows.setdata(k="113", v=5, n=25, m=4)
    windows.setdata(k="111", v=5, n=2, m=4)

    windows.setWindowTitle("QTableWidgetItem")
    windows.resize(1100, 700)    
    windows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: S.nick i tried your method it works find but i want to loop with a dynamic int  while i < j :